# my current position isn't displaying on the console

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

[here's a screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od8Qd.png)

the code was running well before my current position was printing on the console then I terminated the program and ran it again then it just stopped working

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also do not post images of code/data/errors: see [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to decare your position variable outside the function block to be able to access it within your build Widgets.

```dart
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
    late Position position;
// ...
```

Next, you need to update the position state using `setState`;

```dart
    // ...
    setState(() {
      position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition( /* complete the call here*/;
    });
    print(position);
    // ...
```

For any more help or explanation feel free to comment below. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation is cleared and detailed. You can consult this link [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), It's shows the steps to be followed during the implementation of get the current location.

1. Firstly, checking is location service enabled in the device,
2. Secondly, checking and requesting permission to access the position of the device.
3. Finally, get location service when service is enabled and
   permissions are granted .

The following code, it's copied from official documentation:

```
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

Comment: Great pointing out!